# TypeScript: What is the context of P in `T extends infer P`? (unclear where `P` come from)

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I came across this TypeScript snippet yesterday:

```
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends infer P ? keyof P : never
//                    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

It makes me confused: What is being inferred here? I've created a mental model that using `infer` keyword is similar to destructuring in JS – of course this parallel is far from perfect, but it did helped me a lot.

But I can't see any context here: `T extends infer P` ? What am I infering? What is the relation between `P` and `T`?

After testing the snippet in TS playground, I would guess that it have something to do with separating the types that have a constructor from those that don't have one.

```
type test1 = KeysOfUnion<{ name: "Bill"}> // name
type test2 = KeysOfUnion<"Orange"> // number | typeof Symbol.iterator | "toString" | "charAt" etc.
type test3 = KeysOfUnion<1> // "toString" | "valueOf" | "toFixed" etc.
type test4 = KeysOfUnion<true> // "valueOf"
type test5 =  KeysOfUnion<Object> // keyof Object

type test6  = KeysOfUnion<object> // never
type test7 = KeysOfUnion<{}> // never
```

The `object` and `{}` behavior is a little confusing, but I guess it is explained here: [Difference between 'object' ,{} and Object in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-object-in-typescript)

```
type test8 = KeysOfUnion<undefined> // never
type test9 = KeysOfUnion<null> // never
type test10 = KeysOfUnion<never> // never
type test11 = KeysOfUnion<void> // never
```

But the test results are probably rather related  to `keyof P` – still have no clue why `T extends infer P` is used here.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details of the `infer` keyword are well explained in posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067100/why-is-the-infer-keyword-needed-in-typescript).

But `infer` does only play a *minor role* in this generic type. It is only used here to use the effects of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). The creator of this type wanted to distribute each member of a potential union in `T` over the right side of the conditional.

---

The type in your question has one important use: It generates a *union* of all the *keys* of each union member in an *object union*. `T extends infer P` does not really have a special effect here (aside from distribution) as it *just* copies the type `T` into `P`. So let's imagine we would simplify this type to just use `keyof T` directly.

```
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends infer P ? keyof P : never
type KeysOfUnionWithoutInfer<T> = keyof T
```

They might look similar but the first one distributes a union while the second one does not.

Let's call them with an object union.

```
type T0 = KeysOfUnion<{ a: string } | { b: string}>
//   ^? type T0 = "a" | "b"

type T1 = KeysOfUnionWithoutInfer<{ a: string } | { b: string}>
//   ^? type T1 = never
```

Only the first one gives the correct key union.

---

As I said, the `infer` statement is not really needed here. For distribution, a simple `T extends T` would work too.

```
type KeysOfUnionSimpler<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never

type T3 = KeysOfUnionSimpler<{ a: string } | { b: string}>
//   ^? type T3 = "a" | "b"
```

---

Side note: The reason you are seeing `never` as a result when you pass `object`, `{}`, `undefined`, `null`, `never` or `void` is just because using `keyof` on these types produces `never`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAguE8AcFMAIGlrgM4HkBmBVAdgSwPbYA8AKgHywC8sJs0AHqNNgCbKy7brQBOsACrAD8sANZJ86AbABcsbNABuvYBBgIkaLHkIB1XKAAW+AK6gAkl16kK1ceEk1VUOIhQYcBbAGVcAW0gAG2tyKho6RmY2cJF7R1o5BWUeMBcaAAYwty1PQiIAb1gAQzlkUB5OAHNYAF9YAB9YQoAjUvKqmrJgAHpu2H6APRE1OBJM6gAiIomG2AnmidT1EgBGLM0PHWx9I1MLKx4C4raK7Gq6xpaTjq7e-tgh2BGaNeoklWdlgGZ1920vXwBYKHQolWBlU7nWZXcHtM6dHp9QbDNIkH6TaazeYTIA)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I didn't know about the "Distributive Conditional Types". It seems to actually be a quite important feature of TS.

Comment: Great answer, but why is `infer` valid in an `extends` clause? When would you ever want to do `T exrends infer P`, such that P has a useful value.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev - `infer` can **only** be used in conditional types (on the right side of `extends`). Why someone would use it could have different reasons. Mostly to invoke distributive conditional types. There are also certain edge cases where one needs to copy `T` into another generic variable, when `T` would be modified by a conditional true branch.