# Is it possible to Infer the object type from an property inside an interface?

Tags: typescript

I have this interface

```
MyInterface {
 prop1?: string,
 prop2?: string,
}
```

I want to add an `alternative` property, that has the exact same content BUT that infers if some of the properties are defined.

For example

```
const example: MyInterface = {
   prop2: 'some value',
   alternative: {
      prop2: 'some alternative'
   }
}

// alternative is infered as {prop2: string}
const example2: MyInterface = {
   prop2: 'some value',
   alternative: { } // ERROR! prop2 should be defined 
}



// alternative is infered as {prop1: string}
const example3: MyInterface = {
   prop1: 'some value',
   alternative: { 
      prop2: 'this is prop 2'.
   } // ERROR! prop1 should be defined
}
```

Is this possible?

I tried to infer `typeof this` but it did not work.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking (maybe I'm reading it wrong), since [`infer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067851/15291770) is a keyword in TypeScript, or would you want to simply add `alternative?: MyInterface` to the `MyInterface` declaration?

Comment: If you don't have a lot of properties then you could generate a giant union of possible types. Otherwise, you'll need to use a function to validate and infer the types.

Comment: @Harrison I added more examples.

Comment: @katniss for now I am contemplating doing that, but would be nice to have Typescript show errors at design time

Comment: Are you okay with having a creator function? Otherwise you will need to have a giant union

Comment: Yes, I know that. The function I mentioned will check it at compile time.

Comment: then you need a giant union, which will break really soon

Answer (score 0):

You can infer keys by using mapped types and Omit, to exclude the `alternative` key:

```
type Prop<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
} & {
  alternative: Omit<Prop<T>, 'alternative'>;
}

type A = {
  prop1: string
}

const a: Prop<A> = {
  prop1: 'test',
  alternative: {
    prop1: 'test'
  }
}
```

Comment: That will not work if the properties are opcional.

Answer (score 0):

Here is *maybe* a solution, indeed 1) I cannot reproduce your very last case, but in fact I cannot see how that would be consistent; and, 2) I have had to introduce an additional interface.

Though the approach here is sort of the opposite of yours, as it is the shape of `alternative` that determines the acceptable shape of the outer object: and that is because the precedence goes with the specific construction (the specific nesting, which I have not changed), and the fact that the construction is parametrized on `M`, which is indeed the type of `alternative`, not the type of the outer object.  And that is logically very dubious, to the point that I'd rather look into it and into possibly restructuring things.

```
interface MyInterface {
  prop1?: string;
  prop2?: string;
}

type MyAltInterface<M extends MyInterface> = M & {
  alternative: M;
};

function MyAltInterface<M extends MyInterface>(spec: MyAltInterface<M>): MyAltInterface<M> {
  return spec;
}

// alternative is { prop1: string; }
const example1 = MyAltInterface({
  prop1: 'some value',
  alternative: {
    prop1: 'some alternative'
  }
});

// alternative is {}
const example2 = MyAltInterface({
  prop2: 'some value',  // ERROR: 'prop2' does not exist in alternative
  alternative: {}
});

// alternative is { prop2: string; }
const example3 = MyAltInterface({
  prop1: 'some value',  // ERROR: 'prop1' does not exist in alternative
  alternative: {
    prop2: 'this is prop 2'
  }
});

// alternative is { prop1: string; prop2: string; }
const example4 = MyAltInterface({  // ERROR: 'prop2' is missing
  prop1: 'some value',
  alternative: {
    prop1: 'this is prop 2',
    prop2: 'this is prop 2'
  }
});
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkAHKAezIEYB+ALmQGcwpQBzAbhPKrIBMjFm048AvkSJh0ZFBgCCAGzDZIsRBAA8qZBAAekEABNmaLDg1IAfMgC8aZADJCvOCugg4YYADcITKgSPEQwAK4gCD6UIObKqpZ42roGRqbmaria1gAUzHIIgejxmVbJ1gCURSWJmjq2xKRQEGBhULH5EAgSUgD0vcju6l4+-sjAZgR81DRMrOwg3MiSCDGsevpwALZkShA09nEqpUk5jdO0TADkzJRbKL7uYRBXADRuHu3efgGupKQUGbXW73QafEY-K68STiCohfpg4bfMYTQgrNZgDbbXYQASHRTHWpIM68QGCYF3B5PF6vUgIgCiACVGQB5RnXMkCK7IYyUCBmECUTEGCaY0CIzzIiAfJGjX4EGFwvoDIaSuXjSYXARzUSLLjLIirEDrAzYvYAZnxxUJ6lO5zJs2QN0pyEeSmebzpAyZrPZTod3N5-OQguF+lF41iqq+cplap+THOAP42qdYAAFqjUWTkFzoURYfCVeCpRrCBdHfMxFqdQslujjWGzRAACxWmq2zRnL3IH1sjkp7morYTZicUn8R3O0Fuj3vUjRiH+RO8ZNAtOZszZ-i5t6rmsbrNmHN50iKnhAA)